# Cannot configure keyboard input language anymore

Tags: keyboard, languages, input-methods, text-input

On my Xperia S /ICS, I had English and German language input configured. Worked as expected, could switch language on the keyboard. Then I installed a keyboard app and later uninstalled it. Now something strange happened:

The default keyboard is now "Xperia Chinese keyboard". Below this I have

- Google Voice typing            (uncheckable)
- Xperia Chinese Keyboard        (NOT uncheckable)
- Xperia Japanese Keyboard       (NOT uncheckable)
- Xperia Keyboard                (NOT uncheckable)

Now, when I configure the German language (or any other language) in Xperia keyboard, as Writing language, I still cannot use these languages, I only have English and Chinese available.

This is an untenable situation, since I write 70% of my texts in German. Any ideas? Can I get rid of Xperia Keyboard? Install another keyboard that does not kill my phone?

Comment: From Sony Forum I read Factory Reset is the only solution. So I have backup in progress, 4 hours left. Sucks ...

Comment: If the keyboard(s) appear as separate apps in *Settings->Apps->Manage Apps*, it might suffice to delete their caches and data. Never tried this, as I never experienced that situation.

Comment: Great idea Izzy, tried it, too bad did not help. Cache size of Xperia Keyboard is 0, the button is disabled. Event tried "Force Stop" of the stupid keyboard, did not help either. NOw doing factory reset.

Comment: Was worth a try -- chances were 50:50. It had no button to "Delete data"? Too bad... // Btw: when you're done (and hopefully solved your issue), feel free to answer your own question. Might prove helpful to others.